# limit involving rational function and square root

Tags: calculus, limits

When working some exercise problems in my calc book, I came across this limit in which I do not know how to tackle.  It is
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1-\frac{x}{x-1}}{1-\sqrt{\frac{x}{x-1}}}$$
I feel like there is a trick to this one, maybe use L'Hopital's rule or something.  I tried to multiplying by the conjugate but it turned ugly real fast.  Any tips will be helpful.

Comment: Can't you just put $t=\sqrt{\frac{x}{x-1}}$ and solve with $lim_{t\to1}$?

Comment: What does the denominator become when you multiply by the conjugate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $t=\sqrt{\frac{x}{x-1}}.$  Now as $x\to\infty,$ we have $t\to 1$.  Now just factor and limit is much easier.

Comment: Thanks.  Understand it now!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$\frac{1-u}{1-\sqrt{u}}=1+\sqrt{u}$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: the answer is $2$ and use $1-A = (1-\sqrt{A})(1+\sqrt{A})$